# Associated elements in groups and modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, semigroups

We call elements of a commutative ring that divide each other associated (associates).

We can define associates for algebraic structures other than rings as elements that "generate" each other.

The term "generate" will be defined by the structure itself: for groups that will be "powers of each other", "multiples of each other" for rings, "scales of each other" for modules, etc.

Are there interesting properties of such elements in groups, modules, etc., similar to how they appear in gcd, lcm, irreducible elements in rings?

One of the reasons behind the question is that when we say "there is a generator" of a group, or "a basis element" of a module, there is actually a set of interchangeable associated elements each of which can be taken as a "generator" or "basis element" of the structure.

Does it make sense to say "class of associates" instead of "generator", "basis class" instead of "basis element" for an algebraic structure?

And if "yes", isn't it better to generalize associates as elements that "generate the same subset" of an algebraic structure rather than "generate each other"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a well-known notion in semigroup theory, but it has a different name.
Let $M$ be a (not necessarily commutative) monoid. Two elements $x$ and $y$ of $M$ are said to be $\mathcal{J}$-equivalent if there exist $a,b,c,d \in M$ such that $x = ayb$ and $y =cxd$. The $\mathcal{J}$-relation is one of the five [Green's relations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations).

Comment: It looks like it is not the same: all elements of a group are $\mathcal{J}$-equivalent, but not equivalent as group generators (not associates in my terms). Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: I just used the definition given in the first line of your question. Note that two elements are $\mathcal{J}$-equivalent if they divide each other.

Comment: I meant equivalence with respect to generators and other similar properties. I've made corresponding changes in my question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I don't think you have asked an unambiguous question. In the case of groups for example, could you give a precisae definition of what you mean by two elements being equivalent? Then it might be possible to answer the question.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I updated my question. By associates I mean elements that "generate" each other in a way defined in a given algebraic structure. For groups that would be "powers of each other". Is it clear now?

Comment: In a group, $u^n = v$ and $v^m = u$ would give $u^{nm} = u$, whence $u^{nm-1} = 1$. Thus $u$ should generate a cyclic group and $v$ should be a generator of this group.

Comment: In a group aren't two elements always associated with the definition you gave before? Unless you mean something else with "divide each other", in which case you might want to write explicitly its definition. Otherwise, assuming commutativity in the answer given, that definetely gives your notion.

Comment: @H.Kissos: "Generate" does not mean "divide" or "subtract" in case of a group. Generated elements in a group are powers of an element that is the generator. However, there may be a different generator that generates the same elements. Two generators are equivalent if they generate the same set of elements. Two generators of a group are equivalent if and only if they are powers of each other. For example, 1 and 5 are equivalent generators of $\mathbb Z_{12}(+)$; 1 and 5 are powers of each other in $\mathbb Z_{12}(+)$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: There may groups generated by more than one class of associates (defined in this way). Also, I am wondering if the classes of associates of a group appear somewhere else, similar to how associates of a ring appear in gcd, lcm, irreducible elements, etc.

Comment: If I understood your definition correctly, Pin proved in the comment that two elements are "associated" in a group if they are generators of the same cyclic *sub*group. The same holds for semigroups: in a semigroup $u^n=v$ and $v^m=u$ would also give a cyclic group having u and v as generators (the identity is $u^{nm-1}$).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right generalization of "associate elements in a ring" though, if I'm not mistaken, since in rings two elements are associated if they generate the same ideal: you "generate" by multiplying the element with everything, not by multiplying the element with itself (as you would do for "group generation").

Comment: @H.Kissos: I agree. That is why I asked the question. It sounds like there is a better generalization of associates: two elements are associated if they generate the same subset of an algebraic structure, where "generate" is defined by the structure. But in this case we generalize the definition even for rings: 2 and 10 are not associates in the ring $2\mathbb Z_{12}$ since they do not divide each other and themselves. By using the new definition they become associates. Correct?

Comment: The reason this conversation ground out is that you want "generates" to have a clear meaning dictated by the algebraic structure, but it doesn't. Even inside a given algebraic structure there can be more than one meaning for "generates". For example, in a ring $R$, we can ask if $a,b\in R$ generate the same ideal (usual meaning of "associates") or if they generate the same subring. In a group, you can ask if $a$ and $b$ generate the same subgroup or the same sub-semigroup.

Comment: (For example, $1,-1$ in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ generate the same subgroup, namely the whole group, but different sub-semigroups, namely $\mathbb{N}$ and $-\mathbb{N}$.)